# JBAS010441: Failed to load module for driver [org.mariadb]?

Tags: jboss

When I run command:

```
[standalone@localhost:9999 /] /subsystem=datasources/jdbc-driver=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver:add(driver-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver,driver-module-name=org.mariadb,driver-xa-datasource-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.MySQLDataSource)
```

I got an error:

```
{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => "JBAS010441: Failed to load module for driver [org.mariadb]",
    "rolled-back" => true
}
```

Comment: pls, review the driver and verify if you can load the module.

Comment: File mariadb-java-client-1.1.7.jar located in folder /opt/jboss/modules/org/mariadb/main/module.xml

Comment: yes, please review it/re-install it

Comment: no problem, have a good one.